# How to make a 2d Sprite 3d in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, gameobject

I'm developing a maze game in Unity and I'm using png files as mazes. But I want to make this game 3d. How can I add depth to my 2d sprites?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will not add depth to sprite, you can change your sprite to some 3d object.
Cube for example.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html